# How to extract variable names from `aes()` mapping in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Say I have a ggplot2 mapping:

```
mapping = ggplot2::aes(x=ifelse(a, 1, 2), y=a*b)
mapping
```

> Aesthetic mapping:
>
> - `x` -> `ifelse(a, 1, 2)`
> - `y` -> `a * b`

The mapping is provided by user so can be anything. I would like to extract the variables referenced as these are needed to fetch the data and prepare a data frame. I do not want to include all possible columns in my dataframe due to size constraints - only those which will be used in visualisation.

Basically I want a function `f()` such that:

```
f(mapping) == c('a', 'b')
```

Extracting the text itself is quite easy with:

```
expressions = sapply(mapping, quo_name)
expressions
```

```
                x                 y 
"ifelse(a, 1, 2)"           "a * b"
```

But I don't know how to get the variable/column names from the strings.

Comment: How can the solution be `a` and `b`? Notice that you are not mapping `a` and `b` but rather a manipulation of `a` and `b` either you restrict yourself to only using variable names instead of an expression involving variable names. ie do the expression outside the aesthetics, then use a variable name without doing some computations. Otherwise `a` is not  used in the mapping as it is logical but rather `ifelse(a, 1, 2)` is used

Comment: Because if I run `ggplot(df, mapping)` it requires that `df` has columns `a` and `b`, not their transformation.

Comment: In your example, what if you had `aes(ifelse(a,b,d), ifelse(g,ifelse(a,d,f(n)),f(m)))` Notice how many variables are involved. Also will you consider `f` a function to be part of the variables? ie as it needs to be defined.

Comment: The best thing to do is to mutate the `df` itself and then call in the variables. Otherwise this has no limitation. Atleast there should be some kind of limitation.

Comment: Them `a, b, d, g, n, m` is expected. `f` is only allowed to be a function existing in the namespace e.g. `log`.

Comment: *The best thing to do is to mutate the df itself and then call in the variables*. This is not allowed per definition of the problem. The user API is only the mapping created by `aes`.

Comment: But then `a,b,d` can also exist in the namespace rather than in the `df` while the rest exist in the df? Or must the variables exist solely in the df?

Comment: Thanks for answering most of the questions

Comment: *But then `a,b,d` can also exist in the namespace rather than in the df while the rest exist in the df? Or must the variables exist solely in the df?* This is secondary to the core question as the downstream code can easily check if the variable is defined in the namespace or data frame (but in my use case all of them will be defined in `df`).

Comment: lastly, is the `df` provided? if yes this is a quick solve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use base R's `all.vars` without needing the reference data frame.

```r
unique(unlist(lapply(mapping, all.vars)))
#> [1] "a" "b"
```

Comment: `unique(unlist(lapply(mapping, all.vars)))` should work

Comment: Thanks @onyambu - I just noticed that too. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

As long as all the variables reside in the same frame/ environment, you could do:

```
unique(unlist(lapply(mapping, \(x)names(get_all_vars(x)))))
[1] "a"  "b"
```